# Positional parameters for shell not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, command

I am trying to learn bash commands, and some very basic commands are not working as I expect...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5VGK.png

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="john"
other="shawn"
echo $name
echo $other
echo $1
echo $2
echo $#
echo $@
```

Output:

```
$ new
john
shawn


0

$
```

Comment: Please learn how to use copy and paste rather than posting images.  For such a script, making us go and load an image is a nuisance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1, $2, etc and $# have special meaning in bash scripts. They refer to the arguments passed to the bash script, so if you have a script in a file called foo.sh like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of arguments: $#";
echo "First argument: $1";
echo "Second argument: $2";
```

If you chmod +x foo.sh and then run:

```
./foo.sh first second
```

You will see:

```
Number of arguments: 2
First argument: first
Second argument: second
```

$1 refers to the first command line argument passed to the script. The script is foo.sh, so anything after the script name will become a command line argument.

The default command line argument separator is the "space", so when you type ./foo.sh first second, bash stores first into $1 and second into $2.

If you typed:

```
./foo.sh first second third FOURTH fifth
```

bash would store third in the variable $3, FOURTH in the variable $4, and so on.

Comment: I know that but it's not working, see the image. I also referred the Linux command line and shell scripting bible. The tutorial link I referred to was the next page, pls see this previous page:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-variables.htm

Comment: Type exactly what I wrote into a file and save it as foo.sh. Then execute chmod +x ./foo.sh. Then execute ./foo.sh first second. You should see that it works. I think your issue is you are trying to type these commands in to bash directly. Please try what I've suggested.

Comment: yea , its working. but how does it show "first for $1" and second like wise. Which are first and second arguments, can you point, I don't want to sound dumb, but still...

Comment: I guess it can be compared to argv (from sys module) in Python. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, same idea. Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your script named 'new' ? In that case run it as follows one by one and you will get an idea how this works:

```
./new
./new a
./new a b
```

Answer (score 0):

when you ran your script you did not pass any arguments. the number of arguments passed to the scripts are show by echoing "echo $#". and your output clearly shows that the "echo $#" command returned "0" count. pass the argument when you call your script like below

./new argument1 argument2